# Modification of Line Density using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, density, focal-statistics

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.

I need to calculate [Line Density](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/line-density.htm) for polyline vector but the "Search radius" option must be replaced by something like the Neighborhood option in [Focal Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm).

I need to use a rectangle neighborhood instead of a circle neighborhood.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: You say what you want to do but what precisely have you tried/researched towards achieving that goal?

Comment: Do you need line density with a field value or just a count of lines?